# EBNF syntax parser module

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, programming-languages, ebnf

Do you know of a syntax parser module (written in Ruby, Python, Javascript...) that, given a list of tokens and a [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)-like grammar (passed as a simple string), returns the parsed tree? The closest I've found to this is [SimpleParse](http://simpleparse.sourceforge.net/), which is a nice library, but unfortunately it uses a single-step parsing (no tokenization). If possible I'd rather not use libraries in which the implementation is entangled with the language itself ([pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/), [treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/), ...).

I am not worried about the lexing/tokenization because there are a lot of libraries available (and even writing your own is pretty easy), but implementing a ENBF parser is not exactly a trivial task. I've checked the Python wiki [LanguageParsing](http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing) and tested some of them to no avail (maybe I overlooked the one I am looking for, there are so many...)

Comment: Well, what kind of parser is viable depends heavily on the grammar you parse and what you want to do with the input... Why does it have to be language-agnostic and EBNF by the way? If you want anything out of the input (AST or something), you'll need to write code by hand anyway and pure EBNF is only useful for "matches/does not match" recognition.

Comment: @delnan: I am writing a transcompiler (mainly to play with lexers and parsers, nothing serious), and as a first step I'd like to have my language described as a EBNF (or any other syntax describer) and parsed from it (and later generate from it the AST or whatever). Advices in any direction are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching I've decided to take the typical lex/yacc approach using [Jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/) for [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with Clojure at all I've found [Instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse) to be great. You can write in "vanilla" EBNF as a multi-line string (or in a separate file and it even extends EBNF beyond context-free grammars into context sensitive grammars (though I haven't played around with that much).

Comment: I am familiar with Clojure, I'll look into it, thanks!